# Platform Android 4.3, Revision 2 shown as available in online docs but can't be seen in SDK Manager

Tags: android

According to the [Developer Docs](http://developer.android.com/tools/revisions/platforms.html) revision 2 of the 4.3 platform (August 2013) is available. My SDK manager in Eclipse shows revision 1 as installed and nothing newer available. SDK Tools and the plugin are up to date with 22.0.5.

Has anyone managed to install this revision, and if so how please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It finally appeared when the SDK Tools Rev 22.2 became available. Perhaps it was just a documentation error - it wouldn't be the first!